VK bot API не принимает файл
Необходимо отправить картинку как файл в личные сообщения от имени сообщества в ВКонтакте. Вот мой код:

import VkBot from 'node-vk-bot-api';
import fs from 'fs';

const bot = new VkBot({
    token: "token",
});

const uploadServer = await bot.execute('docs.getMessagesUploadServer', { peer_id: peer_id, type: 'doc'});
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', await fs.openAsBlob('./img.png'), 'img.png');

const response = await fetch(uploadServer.upload_url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
});
const data = await response.json();

console.log(data)

На что в консоль выводится следующее:
{ error: 'no_file', error_descr: 'no_file' }
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в чем проблема

Как минимум уберите Content-Type, потому что его добавлением вы затёрли boundary и сделали ваш запрос нечитаемым
